# Ruby Require Statement and file locations

Tags: ruby, require

I am trying to use the `require` command in Ruby. I'm using CodeRunner to run my code. The problem I'm running into is that the require statement is just using a string "chunky_png." I have a folder full of library files that this code needs to use. I'm not sure A)where to put the folder and B)if I need to point to that folder somehow? Here is my code, below that is the error I'm getting. I have the folder of library files in the same folder as the PNGdecode.rb file that I'm trying to run:

```
require 'chunky_png'

class ChunkyPNG::Image
  def at(x,y)
    ChunkyPNG::Color.to_grayscale_bytes(self[x,y]).first
  end
end

img = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('engine.png')

sobel_x = [[-1,0,1],
           [-2,0,2],
           [-1,0,1]]

sobel_y = [[-1,-2,-1],
           [0 , 0, 0],
           [1 , 2, 1]]

edge = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(img.width, img.height, ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT)

for x in 1..img.width-2
  for y in 1..img.height-2
    pixel_x = (sobel_x[0][0] * img.at(x-1,y-1)) + (sobel_x[0][1] * img.at(x,y-1)) + (sobel_x[0][2] * img.at(x+1,y-1)) +
          (sobel_x[1][0] * img.at(x-1,y))   + (sobel_x[1][1] * img.at(x,y))   + (sobel_x[1][2] * img.at(x+1,y)) +
          (sobel_x[2][0] * img.at(x-1,y+1)) + (sobel_x[2][1] * img.at(x,y+1)) + (sobel_x[2][2] * img.at(x+1,y+1))

    pixel_y = (sobel_y[0][0] * img.at(x-1,y-1)) + (sobel_y[0][1] * img.at(x,y-1)) + (sobel_y[0][2] * img.at(x+1,y-1)) +
          (sobel_y[1][0] * img.at(x-1,y))   + (sobel_y[1][1] * img.at(x,y))   + (sobel_y[1][2] * img.at(x+1,y)) +
          (sobel_y[2][0] * img.at(x-1,y+1)) + (sobel_y[2][1] * img.at(x,y+1)) + (sobel_y[2][2] * img.at(x+1,y+1))

    val = Math.sqrt((pixel_x * pixel_x) + (pixel_y * pixel_y)).ceil
    edge[x,y] = ChunkyPNG::Color.grayscale(val)
  end
end
edge.save('engine_edge.png')
```

The error:

```
PNGdecode.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- chunky_png (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually [`chunky_png`](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) is a [gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/), that is, a library **package**. You should install it through RubyGems ruby packaging system.

**First**, install [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) if it is not already installed. *(If you can type `gem` command and it shows its help, then go to the second step)*

**Second**, install this *gem* using command:

```
gem install chunky_png
```

This will download not only this library, but also its dependencies, install and configure them in such a way that you could do `require 'chunky_png'` from **any** dir without taking all the library files with it.

This is the normal way for installing external libraries in Ruby.

***Note:** you may want to prepend the latter command with `sudo` if you are on Ubuntu Linux system and you want to install the gem system-wide (for all users)*

***Note 2:** if you finally want to distribute your Ruby application that requires gems, you'd better use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com) so other people can install all your dependencies automatically without the need to parse error messages and install required gems manually one-by-one*

Comment: NIA, thanks a lot. I figured out the install part, but now I'm getting this error: >/Users/mchristensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PNGDecoder-aajzzwvmnydgadekuteewrxhjsfe/Build/Products/Debug/PNGDecoder.app/Contents/Resources/rb_main.rb:14:in `<main>': no such file to load -- chunky_png (LoadError)